# Role of different exponential families in generalized linear models

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, exponential-family

I've gone through a variety of introductions to generalized linear models (GLM), and there's always a point in the discussion that confuses me. The story often begins saying that $P(y|x)$ belongs to a member of the *exponential family* of distributions. Shortly thereafter, and without explanation, everyone always switches to the *canonical exponential family*, and finally to the *exponential dispersion family* of distributions, with an assumption that the dispersion parameter $\phi$ is known and constant.

**Examples**

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-ix97pw0xY) is an example from an MIT OpenCourseWare lecture series (lectures 21-23 are on GLM). The exponential family discussion begins towards the end of lecture 21 and is much of the focus of lecture 22.

As another example, the [Wikipedia article on GLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model) begins the Overview section with the statement

> *"In a generalized linear model (GLM), each outcome Y of the dependent variables is assumed to be generated from a particular distribution in an exponential family"*

...and in the definition states (emphasis mine)

> The GLM consists of three elements:
>
> 1. An **exponential family** of probability distributions.
> 2. A linear predictor η = Xβ.
> 3. A link function g such that E(Y|X) = μ = g−1(η).

In the following line, however, the article begins discussing the overdispersed exponential family and limits further discussion to scalar parameters.

**My Question**

What I'm missing is why instructors are using these smaller classes of distributions - is it just because the examples are more tractable for a classroom, or are the log-likelihoods not guaranteed to be convex, or something else?

If it's the case that GLM only applies to exponential dispersion distributions, why is the requirement always stated as the broader, multi-parameter exponential family?

Comment: GLMs do only apply to exponential dispersion models. EDMs do not need to be canonical. They are more special than exponential families in some ways and more general in other ways. If you want to ask why some source has given you a misleading impression, you would need to cite the source before we could comment on it.

Comment: An EDM is a linear exponential family when the dispersion is known, but might not be an exponential family at all when the dispersion is unknown. It's not true that "everyone always" exposits GLMs the same way, but it would be remiss of an instructor to not mention the concept of an exponential family or the concept of a canonical link.

Comment: If you want to see GLMs defined precisely but in about as few words as possible, see Section 3 of an old article of mine : http://www.statsci.org/smyth/pubs/goodness.pdf

Comment: Prof. Smyth, thanks for your comments! I was just reading another of your papers actually, "Generalized Linear Models with Varying Dispersion". I'll update my post with some references where I find the confusing definition.

Comment: @GordonSmyth, I'm curious if you have thoughts about the examples that I added?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to write more. IMO the wikipedia glm probability distribution presentation is unhelpful, so I'd advise you to ignore it in favour of clearer presentations. I don't have time to listen to 3 hours of the MIT course.

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/413825/definition-of-exponential-family-with-dispersion-parameter/413833#413833